# How to divide one matrix by another in Stata

Tags: matrix, stata, division

I have created two matrices with the following commands:

```
tab year region if x==1, matcell(cases)  
tab year region, matcell(total)
```

Both matrices are 10 columns by 9 rows. 
I now want to create a new matrix with percents which
equals:  p = (cases/total)*100

But I cannot find the command to do so in Stata? is there an easy way?

Comment: Please post reproducible examples. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve explains.

Answer (score 3):

We don't have your own data to experiment, so consider this analogue.

We want the first table as a percent of the second table. It is easy to get there directly, as we can just calculate first what we want to show.

```
. webuse nlsw88, clear 
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

. tab race collgrad if married == 1

           |   college graduate
      race | not colle  college g |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
     white |       862        288 |     1,150 
     black |       224         50 |       274 
     other |        12          6 |        18 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     1,098        344 |     1,442 


. tab race collgrad

           |   college graduate
      race | not colle  college g |     Total
-----------+----------------------+----------
     white |     1,217        420 |     1,637 
     black |       480        103 |       583 
     other |        17          9 |        26 
-----------+----------------------+----------
     Total |     1,714        532 |     2,246 


. egen toshow = mean(100 * (married == 1)), by(race collgrad)

. tabdisp race collgrad, c(toshow) format(%2.1f)

----------------------------------------------
          |          college graduate         
     race | not college grad      college grad
----------+-----------------------------------
    white |             70.8              68.6
    black |             46.7              48.5
    other |             70.6              66.7
----------------------------------------------
```

But let's show how to work with the matrices. Note that what you ask for is **not** matrix division as usually understood in linear algebra, as the division 
is elementwise. The easiest way to do that (now) is to call up Mata.

```
quietly tab race collgrad if married == 1, matcell(num) 
quietly tab race collgrad, matcell(den)
mata : st_matrix("wanted", 100 * st_matrix("num") :/ st_matrix("den"))
mat li wanted

wanted[3,2]
           c1         c2
r1   70.82991  68.571429
r2  46.666667  48.543689
r3  70.588235  66.666667
```

Note that it's more awkward to do in Stata alone, but perfectly possible with `matewd` once installed. But Stata fairly tags such programs as "historical" as since Stata 9 Mata has allowed a one-line solution. `matewd` is included in `dm69`, even though it is not mentioned in the brief summary.

```
. search dm69, entry historical 


STB-50  dm69  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  Further new matrix commands
        (help matdelrc, matewm, matmad, matpow if installed)  . . .  N. J. Cox
        7/99    pp.5--9; STB Reprints Vol 9, pp.29--34
        collection of new matrix commands providing additional matrix
        checking, management, element-wise operators, maximum absolute
        difference, and power
```

Comment: So, translate to your own dataset. Note that your question says `x`; now you say `sex`. The principles are the same.